# Java click button to open URI: “Firefox can't find the server at www.%u.com.”

Tags: java, linux, hyperlink, uri, linkbutton

I want to have a button that, when clicked, opens the default browser and points to a URI.

I have some code that works in my testing, when run in Netbeans 7.x, but it fails when deployed as a JAR. My Java app runs on Linux only.

Anyone see the problem or know of another solution?

This code is in my main form:

```
linkBtnTest = new LinkButton(
                new URI("http://www.example.com/some-page"),
                "Click here for blah blah blah");
        linkBtnTest.init();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.log(ex);
    }
    Accessibility.increaseFontSize(linkBtnTest, 
            ApplicationContext.get().getFontIncreaseSize());
    TestPanel.add(linkBtnTest);
```

Here's the class. I didn't write this code and I'm open to other suggestions:

```
package com.example.client;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class LinkButton extends JButton
    implements ActionListener {
        /** The target or href of this link. */
        private URI target;
        final static private String defaultText = "<HTML>Click the <FONT color=\"#000099\"><U>link</U></FONT>"
            + " to go to the example website.</HTML>";

        public LinkButton(URI target, String text) {
            super(text);
            this.target = target;
            //this.setText(text);
            this.setToolTipText(target.toString());
        }
        public LinkButton(URI target) {
            this( target, target.toString() );
        } 
        public void init() {
            this.addActionListener(this);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            open(target);
        }
        class OpenUrlAction implements ActionListener {
        @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            open(target);
        }
        }
        private static void open(URI uri) {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
                } catch (IOException e) { /* TODO: error handling */ }
            } else { /* TODO: error handling */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have a class you don't use? (`OpenUrlAction`), why is `open()` static? other than those I don't see why it shouldn't work.